# BootstrapのModalで別htmlの読み込みができましたが、読み込む要素を指定したい

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

[こちらを参照して別htmlを表示させています。](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y7jDj2hORWmJ95c96qoG?p=preview)

しかし、読み込む要素を指定することができません。
例えばですが上記ページの内容を元にして
「Lab6.html」内の
'div class="panel-body"'のみを読み込ませることは可能でしょうか。

jqueryの.loadで試してみましたが、html内のソースが全て読み込まれてしまうため、
対応方法が検討もつきません。
どなたかご教示いただければ大変助かります。
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

仮に、Lab6.htmlの内容が以下のとき

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>test</h1>
    <div class="panel-body">これそれあれ</div>
    <div>hoge</div>
</body>
</html>
```

div class="panel-body"をjqueryで抜き出す一例です。
(div class="panel-body"が一つだけの時の例です、複数存在する時は、.eq()とか使って取り出しましょう。)

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $.get("lab6.html",function(data){
                var jq_obj = $($.parseHTML(data));
                $("#data").append(jq_obj.filter("div.panel-body"));
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body id="data">    
</body>
</html>
```